# Solr/Lucene Copyfield summary

Tags: solr, lucene, summary

I am using Solr. I created a copyfield "text" which contains multiple normal fields. When I do a search, the "text" field is returned as an array, but I cannot define programatically in what field the search string is found.

Is it possible to create like a summary of the field with the result ? A kind of dynamic field that holds a snippet of the field which yielded the result.

So When I search in: Description, Information, Additional_Information .... fields,

I want to get a snippet of the text (with maximum amount of characters) of the field in which the search term was found.

Comment: Try to set the highlighter to the source fields (Description, Information, Additional_Information). Hope Im right :-)

Comment: Ok, The highlighting is on the bottom of the results, not in each result set :) thx

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting does not work on multivalued fields + highlighting appears as a seperate part at the bottom of the response. (thx to aitchnyu)